# Why is wget POST giving 400 Bad Request?

Tags: json, rest, unix, curl, wget

I am trying to use wget to POST a .json file to a site using the REST api. Specifically I am trying to create an issue in JIRA from my command line. I am aware that the easiest way to do this is using cURL; however, Solaris' native compiler has an issue with cURL versions before 7.49.0, so I can't connect via https which is a requirement, and I can't update cURL as I'm working on a company machine.

Every time I try to use wget to POST I get an ERROR: 400 Bad Request. It occurs to me that usually this is a problem with the json I'm trying to send but I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

OS: Solaris 10
Version: wget 1.9.1

Command:

```
wget --post-file=data.json --http-user=[userID] --http-passwd=[userPass] --header="Content-Type: application/json" -i "uri.txt"
```

data.json:

```
    {
        "fields": {
            "project":
            { 
                "id": "10200"
            },
            "summary": "Creating issue remotely.",
            "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
            "issuetype": {
                "name": "Story"
            },
            "customfield_11600": {
                "id": "11303"
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I think my header is not correct when I send out my http POST. In my wget command above I set the Content-Type to application/json; however, looking at the debug information there is two Content-Type spaces in my header.

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: application/json
```

Could it be that I'm setting my Content-Type incorrectly and the POST is being sent with the wrong encoding?

**UPDATE 2**

I think I've ruled out the above update as an issue, as removing the application/json content-type gives a 415 Unsupported Media Type error, implying that adding it makes the POST send the correct media type.

I've gotten a curl command to work properly on my windows machine and it connects via http1.1 automatically while wget connects via http1.0, I believe that when connecting via http1.0 the data being sent is appended on the end of the URI. Could this be why the server believes the json to be incorrect?

Comment: Did you try do send just a content via '–post-data' instead of post-file ? Also you probably need to use content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded is sending as a file

Comment: @Stan Using --post-data or changing Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded still give me 400 Bad Request.

Comment: do you have source code for endpoint you are sending request to? To make sure you have correct data structure

Comment: I don't; however, when working on my windows machine, and using curl, I sent the same json file and it worked perfectly. So the only thing I can think of is that wget and curl are somehow formatting the contents of the file differently when they send it.

Comment: then you can probably use some network monitor to see difference between curl and wget requests (maybe some headers)